# Calculate hours worked between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a Bookings table and I need to calculate the total hours a staff member has worked in a week, but I need it to cut off dates between Monday midnight and the following Monday at midnight.

```
create table Bookings (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null, start datetime, finish datetime, staffId int)

insert into Bookings (start, finish, staffId) values ('2022-06-19 21:00:00', '2022-06-20 07:00:00', 1)
insert into Bookings (start, finish, staffId) values ('2022-06-24 21:00:00', '2022-06-25 07:00:00', 1)
insert into Bookings (start, finish, staffId) values ('2022-06-25 21:00:00', '2022-06-26 07:00:00', 1)
insert into Bookings (start, finish, staffId) values ('2022-06-26 21:00:00', '2022-06-27 07:00:00', 1)
```

```
select *, datediff(MINUTE, start, finish)/60.0
from Bookings
where staffid = 1 and start between '2022-06-19' and '2022-06-27'
```

[image]

I need row 1 to start at 2022-06-20 00:00 and row 4 to finish at 2022-06-27 00:00 so the hours for row 1 would be 7, and for row 4 would be 3, thus totaling 30 hours instead of 40.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: *"I need row 1 to start at 2022-06-20 00:00 "* Why? `2022-06-19T21:00:00` is 19 hours after the value in your `WHERE` (`2022-06-19`).

Comment: i'm trying to calculate the hours a staff has worked for a particular week, from Monday to the Sunday. I included the Sun 19th incase the staff worked any night shifts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you need to do here is firstly change your `WHERE` to look at the `finish` time being *after* your start value, and the `start` time being *before* your finish value. Then for the hours worked, you need to use a `CASE` expression to return the column or input parameters value, depending which is lesser/greater:

```sql
DECLARE @Start date = '20220620',
        @Finish date = '20220627';

SELECT ID,
       staffId,
       finish,
       staffId,
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CASE WHEN start < @Start THEN @Start ELSE start END,CASE WHEN finish > @Finish THEN @Finish ELSE finish END) / 60. AS Hours
FROM dbo.Bookings
WHERE staffId = 1
  AND finish > @Start
  AND start < @Finish;
```